# Ubuntu 19.04 doesnt work with 5.0 kernel but works with 4.18

Tags: kernel, 19.04

I have updated to 18.10 from 18.04 and then updated to 19.04 but after the update the system will not open, remaining stuck at black screen with a cursor at top left corner

I can use terminal with ctrl+alt+F2 and login and have wifi internet connection but gui is just does not show up.

I can boot normally the system with 4.18 kernel from selecting at grub menu

I think it might be a gpu driver issue because while i was using ubuntu 18.04 LTS i had driver issues too. System settings was saying `llvmpipe` (llvm 8.0, 256 bits) that what i am using as gpu

Secure boot is disabled and i use uefi system

My laptop details:

- İ7-8750H
- Gtx-1050
- 256ssd+1tb hdd
- 16gb ram

And lastly i have dual boot installed on my ssd, windows 10 + ubuntu

Comment: Kernel 4.8?  is the Ubuntu 16.10 kernel?  or did you mean 4.18 which is the 18.10 kernel.

Comment: yes i mean 4.18 my bad sorry

Comment: i realized that i can boot the system with the 5.0 kernel but with nomodeset configuriation from grub2 menu

Comment: but setting app says gpu is unknown ??

Comment: Many have found the nvidia driver `418` is flawed and have success with the `396` driver instead. Also kernel 5 being new is likely to have problems for awhile so use kernel 4.18 until such time the bugs are worked out.

Comment: Okey then i will try 396 driver